# Convert string(dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm) to datetime format

Tags: c#

I have string with datetime format dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm.I want to calculate duration between two dates but failed to get datetime in correct format.please help.
thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please show your work and where you stuck.

Comment: You say you've "failed" - that suggests you've tried something already. Please show what you've tried and explain what happened.

Answer (score 0):

After parsing date string create two dates.

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime();
DateTime date2 = new DateTime();

date1 = DateTime.Parse("22/05/2013 09:50:00");
date2 = DateTime.Parse("22/05/2014 09:50:00");
```

Then use [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) structure to calculate interval:

```
TimeSpan ts_interval = date2 - date1;
```

You can use the following properties:

```
ts_interval.TotalSeconds;
ts_interval.TotalMinutes;
ts_interval.TotalHours;
```

For more visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can use build in method

```
DateTime.Parse("12/05/1999 18:25");
```

you can also check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969649/datetime-asp-net/21970245#21970245)